# Can't export TaskJuggler with cyrillics symbols from Spacemacs

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

I start using org-mode in whole my life and often use TaskJuggler for export Gant's Diagram.  All work perfect, but sometimes I have Cyrillic text in my tasks and properties, and when trying export from space maps to TJ3 with open html report, I'm get the error in message buffer:

```
~/Documents/OrgMode/TaskJuggler.tjp:0: Error: UTF-8 encoding error in line 1: project nil "<?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?> <?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?>" "1.0" 2018-05-03 +280d {
org-taskjuggler-compile: TaskJuggler failed with errors: Error: UTF-8 encoding error in line 1: project nil "<?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?> <?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?>" "1.0" 2018-05-03 +280d {
```

How can I fix that?
Now I use clear export to TJ3, and after that use CLI:

`tj3 TaskJuggler.tjp  -o ./reports`

And only after that command I got what I need.

Comment: Check this answer https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/41683/18445

Comment: @AdamFaryna and community can we duplicate answer here from emacs thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting language environment variables in Emacs helped in my case:

```
(setenv "LC_ALL" "en_US.UTF-8")
(setenv "LANG" "en_US.UTF-8")
(setenv "LANGUAGE" "en_US.UTF-8")
(setenv "LC_COLLATE" "en_US.UTF-8")
(setenv "LC_CTYPE" "en_US.UTF-8")
(setenv "LC_MESSAGES" "en_US.UTF-8")
(setenv "LC_MONETARY" "en_US.UTF-8")
(setenv "LC_NUMERIC" "en_US.UTF-8")
(setenv "LC_TIME" "en_US.UTF-8")
```

Check what locale settings you use in shell environment by running `locale` and set your emacs variables accordingly.

As @Bimawa mention in [other thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33609/taskjuggler-failed-produce/41683#41683), for Spacemacs this code should be added in `(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ())` function in `.spacemacs` dot file.